# iOS: I would like to add "." to an NSInteger and display it as NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, formatting, numbers

I got an **NSInteger** that looks like "8444". I would like to display it in the following way "84.44". **If the integer looks like "84455" then it should look like "844.55"**. If it is "85544433" then it should look like "855.444.33".

Any suggestion? I wanted to use **NSStringWithFormat** but I do not know which tags to provide.

Comment: In the third case, do you mean 855,444.33?  Are you concerned about locales where the group separator is . and the decimal separator is . - ie. 855.444,33 ?

Comment: Exactly. I prefer the International standard (which uses "." to separate values and "," for the decimal places") but in the U.S. works the opposite way. So I am trying to have an arbitrary way to localize the displayed of the values (as well as trying to do how to format a NSInteger in either way).

Comment: This is what `NSNumberFormatter` is for. The a number like 1000 will appear as `1,000`, or `1.000`, or `1 000` as appropriate to the user's locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the representation of a number depending on the locale, in fact, it would be better if you would allow iOS to detect the proper locale and apply the corresponding format, it can vary a lot from one to other country according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark.

In your example you are using a NSInteger but I am guessing that the 2 last numbers are the decimal part, if so, you could do it this way and keep locale consistency:

```
NSInteger integer = 8444;
// Convert integet to decimal
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((float)integer/100)];
// Create formatter
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
// Conver number to string
NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

That code will use the locale configured on iOS, but if you want to force one specifically, you can do it by adding these lines before the conversion:

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. Added the "!=0" check as suggested in the other answer. Great class

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
- (NSString *)formattedStringFromInteger:(NSInteger)number {
    NSString *result = @"0";
    if (number != 0) {
        NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
        numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = @".";
        NSString *string = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(number * 10)];
        result = [string substringToIndex:string.length - 1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

> 8444 -> 84.44
>   101 -> 1.01
>   10100000 -> 101.000.00
>   0 -> 0

Comment: Good solution. +1, if I could give u plus 2 I would but had to accept the other one as was using the localization system. However I added the "!=0" check on the solution.